# .NET regex inner text between td, span, a tag

Tags: c#, regex

```
<table >
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="height: 14px">
            tdtext1
            <a>hyperlinktext1<a/> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            tdtext2
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>spantext1</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my sample text. **How to write a regular expression in C# to get the matches** for the innertext for `td`, `span`, hyperlinks.

Comment: Regular expressions are part of the .NET Framework. They work the same for C#, VB.NET, F#, or any .NET language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cringe every time I hear the words regex and HTML in the same sentence. I would suggest checking out the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) on CodePlex which is a very tolerant HTML parser that lets you use XPath queries against the parsed document. It's much cleaner and the person that inherits your code will thank you!

**EDIT**

As per the comments below, here's some examples of how to get the InnerText of those tags. Very simple.

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("...your sample html...");

// all <td> tags in the document
foreach (HtmlNode td in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td")) {
    Console.WriteLine(td.InnerText);
}

// all <span> tags in the document
foreach (HtmlNode span in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span")) {
    Console.WriteLine(span.InnerText);
}

// all <a> tags in the document
foreach (HtmlNode a in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a")) {
    Console.WriteLine(a.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with the Xpath queries for the above parsing requirement.

Comment: I added a code example. I don't know how complex your XPath requirements are but I guarantee you it'll be much easier with XPath than Regex.

Comment: Lucky you only cringe, unlike this guy, who totally lost it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Igor, oh my god that is hilarious. I bet a hooker got murdered that night.

Answer (score 1):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //...
       // using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) // WebClient class inherits IDisposable
       // {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://www.freeclup.com");

            foreach (HtmlNode span in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(span.InnerText);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

      //  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
        const string pattern = @"[a|span|td]>\s*?(?<text>\w+?)\s*?</\w+>";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
        MatchCollection m = regex.Matches(x);
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        foreach (Match match in m)
        {
            list.Add(match.Groups["text"].Value);
        }
```

Comment: -1: you didn't try this, did you? You also didn't get the point that, in general, you cannot use regular expressions against HTML.

Comment: Did you realize that HTML is not a regular language, so regular expressions don't work in all cases? And, BTW, the `[abc]` syntax means, `a` or `b` or `c`, and so does `[a-c]`. You meant to use parentheses there: `(a | span | td)` is what you wanted.

Comment: The XPath example could easily be reduced to one loop using the same alternation expression. I believe you also misspelled douche.

Comment: Parse [X]HTML with regex? Blasphemy! Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags